# Convert a Collection of Strings to a Collection of Users. Have a method userService.findById()

Tags: java, spring

I have an application in which I pass conferenceDto object with User Ids to my conferenceService where it needs to be added to a Conference Model. The problem is that the conferenceDto list of user ids is a string (ex. "2,4"). I am trying to find the best way of turning this collection of strings to a list of objects of type *User*

My conferenceService method:

```
@Override
public Conference updateConference(@Valid ConferenceDto conferenceDto){
    Authentication user1 = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    User user = userService.findByUsername(user1.getName());

    Optional<Conference> conferenceTemp = findById(conferenceDto.getConference_id());


    if (nameExist(conferenceDto.getName()) && !conferenceDto.getName().equals(conferenceTemp.get().getName())) {
        throw new ConferenceAlreadyExistException(
                "There is a conference with that name: "
                        +  conferenceDto.getName());
    }
    Conference conference = new Conference();
    conference.setConference_id(conferenceDto.getConference_id());
    conference.setCreator(user);
    conference.setName(conferenceDto.getName());
    conference.setDescription(conferenceDto.getDescription());
    conference.setStartConference(conferenceDto.getStartConference());
    conference.setEndConference(conferenceDto.getEndConference());
    conference.setStudents(Collections.singletonList(userService.findById(conferenceDto.getStudents()))); // doesnt work this way because findById requires type long but here I am using Collection<Strings>
    return conferenceRepository.save(conference);
}
```

I am quite new to Java and Spring so Im not sure if this needs a for loop to fill a new list and then pass it to conference.setStudents or it can be done another way. Any tips is very appreciated!

p.s. Type Conference's students is a `Collection<User>`

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I did create a for loop and it turns the collection of strings into a collection of users like I want to. Although, it does not save to my attendance_table for some reason

Changed conferenceService method to:

```
@Override
public Conference updateConference(@Valid ConferenceDto conferenceDto){
    Authentication user1 = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    User user = userService.findByUsername(user1.getName());

    Optional<Conference> conferenceTemp = findById(conferenceDto.getConference_id());


    if (nameExist(conferenceDto.getName()) && !conferenceDto.getName().equals(conferenceTemp.get().getName())) {
        throw new ConferenceAlreadyExistException(
                "There is a conference with that name: "
                        +  conferenceDto.getName());
    }
    Conference conference = new Conference();
    conference.setConference_id(conferenceDto.getConference_id());
    conference.setCreator(user);
    conference.setName(conferenceDto.getName());
    conference.setDescription(conferenceDto.getDescription());
    conference.setStartConference(conferenceDto.getStartConference());
    conference.setEndConference(conferenceDto.getEndConference());

    Collection<User> userCollection = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String s: conferenceDto.getStudents()){
        System.out.println(s);
        userCollection.add(userService.findById((long) Integer.parseInt(s)).get());
    }
    conference.setStudents(userCollection);
    return conferenceRepository.save(conference);
}

private boolean nameExist(String name) {
    return conferenceRepository.findByName(name) != null;
}
```